# Excel - VBA - Access: Date Selection Solution

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking for a direction, assuming that surely someone has had to do something similar and I'm making this more difficult than it is.

We have an Access DB, feeds to a pivot table in Excel, which is in turn used to supply charts for a "user dashboard." This is 2010, so no slicers.

My problem is that that DB is updated adding months to a field. There is a listbox in the dashboard that will allow the user to select a specific month and see stats for that time. I'm having a couple problems even getting started and would like to make sure I'm going about this the simplist/most efficient way.

My thought was to populate the listbox with the 'month' fields from the pivot table. I'm not quite sure how I'm going to do that with VBA (I have a couple ideas), but if that's the best route then I'll figure it out.

But, has anyone had a similar need, and found a better solution? I have a bunch of buttons to handle other fields, but I would really like to allow for the user to select a date/month/range...whatever. Surely this is a common, easily managed desire, no?

Comment: Why not just populate the listbox with the 12 months as there will only ever be 12.  Then when the user makes the selection, query your DB using that month.

Comment: That's definetely where I'm gonna start. And that will hold the higher ups off for a bit. I literally just left a meeting in which we are ok with having that for a bit. But there will be a need to further report on MTD and YTD down the line.

Comment: Excel 2010 does have slicers...  I think it's 2007 that does not.  Are you definitely on 2010?

Comment: why not include the month field as filter in the pivot table itself?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I'm using 2007.

Comment: The month field is a filter already. But the "viewer" doesn't see the pivot table. It's part of a dashboard with charts, etc. for users who aren't Excel proficient.

Answer (score 0):

I'd put this in with the conversation you're having with a couple of people above, but I don't have enough rep to do that yet.

I had a similar dashboard issue years ago. Resolved it by adding a dropdown beside the month box (which was a dropdown in my case, not a listbox) with the options "Year to date" and "Month to date". By definition selecting a past month and MTD gave you the whole month, whereas selecting the current month can only ever give you MTD. Same thing with YTD - it would give you the combined stats for the current year to date instead of just one month.

The month dropdown in my dashboard was populated based on the current data in the pivot, which in turn was controlled from the database. We used a 25-month rolling select for the data and showed only the last 13 months in the month dropdown. That gave us a full 12 month spread of historical data to work from if someone chose the oldest month we offered them, yet kept the size of the pivot cache manageable

I used a dropdown for the options instead of option buttons or a checkbox, because I had a suspicion that delivering what was asked for would lead to additional requests. I was right. Eventually we had options for "Last year to date" (how we were tracking this day last year), "Quarter to date", "Financial year to date", and so on. Adding extra choices to the dropdown box was easier than rearranging the dashboard to accommodate the proliferating requirements.